# how to update mysql table from Serialised json?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have get Serialised from [Nestable](http://dbushell.github.io/Nestable/), but I don't know how to write php code update my database like **wordpress**:

```
$data = '[{"id":1},{"id":2,"children":[{"id":3},{"id":4},{"id":5,"children":[{"id":6},{"id":7},{"id":8}]},{"id":9},{"id":10}]},{"id":11},{"id":12}]';

function extract_value($value,$order=0){
        if(is_array($value)){
            foreach($value as $k => $v){
                echo "UPDATE vod_page_menu SET ordering = '$order', parent_id = '$v' WHERE id = '$v'; <br/>";
                extract_value($v,$order+1);
            }       
        }
    }
$json = json_decode($data,true);
extract_value($json);
```

Comment: you've got some code there; can you tell us what about it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first decode the JSON, then you can use it in PHP:

```
$data = json_decode($data, true);
foreach ($data as $id => $value) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function extract_value($array,$parent=0,$i=1){


        foreach($array as $k => $v) {
            $id = $array[$k]['id'];

            echo "UPDATE vod_page_menu SET ordering = '$i', parent_id = '$parent' WHERE id = '$id'; <br/>";

            if(isset($array[$k]['children'])){

                $children = $array[$k]['children'];
                foreach($children as $key => $obj){
                    $child = $children[$key]['id'];

                    $i++;

                    echo "UPDATE vod_page_menu SET ordering = '$i', parent_id = '$id' WHERE id = '$child'; <br/>";

                    if(isset($children[$key]['children']))
                    extract_value($children[$key]['children'],$child,++$i);

                }

            }   
            $i++;               

        }
    }
```